# UIScrollView and two-way scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I'm having some trouble working with UIScrollView in my current project. My intention is to have a variable-size drawable canvas which can extend beyond both sides of the screen, and whose size is determined by the user at runtime. For this purpose, I put in a UIScrollView with a Content View inside of it in my View Controller. Unfortunately, Interface Builder keeps pestering me to define the X and Y axes of my Content View as a constant sizes which isn't possible given my specifications. I've even set the ScrollView.contentSize programmatically in my viewDidLoad method and Interface builder is still giving me errors. All other tutorials I've seen have only talked about one-way scrolling with UIScrollView, so here I am. Here's some screenshots of my storyboard hierarchy as well to make things more clear:
[Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0FEO.png)
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbnr8.png)

Does anyone have any experience/workarounds for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Interface builder is TRYING to be helpful and make sure that you don't have arbitrary constraints on your content view.

Remember that Interface Builder just cares about the initial state of the views it loads.  It does not care what you do with them after they have been loaded.

Make IB happy by giving it some rational initial size for your content view.  Then programatically after your scroll view loads you can resize the content view **and** set the scroll view's content size programmatically.